# How to render the 3D View, Editor view?

Tags: 3d-view

This may sounds strange but I want to create a video and show the steps when adding the different effects to te scene. I want to have a high quality picture of the 3D View. Can I make this without taking screenshots?

Comment: Window menu "Make Screencast", the settings are in the User Properties view. If you want to do anything serious use a third party piece of software. In windows the Game recorder works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window menu "Make Screencast", the settings are in the User Properties view. If you want to do anything serious use a third party piece of software. In windows the Game recorder works well. – rob Oct 10 at 8:49

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to record an interactive session, but an animated one, you can use "OpenGL render active wiewport": the button is in the footer of the 3D window, the last one on the right. It works exactly like a normal rendered animation: the paths, settings etc are in the Render panel, and the start/end are the ones set in the Timeline.